# how to write to cells of another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 20 worksheets in a workbook. Each of them have a particular data value in the same `cell(i,j)` . I want to add another worksheet at the end that can store all these data values in its cells, one below the other.
i wrote a code for that

```
Sheet21.Range(Cells(i, 0)).Value = myWorksheet.Range(Cells(221, 2)).Value
    i = i + 1
```

but it is giving this error `" Object variable or with block variable not set"`
I am a beginner and have no idea how to debug this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please add the entire code, not only one line ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example adding a new sheet, naming it "Summary" and looping over the original sheets to gather the data:

```
Sub Luxation()
    Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    i = 7
    j = 11
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set myWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Summary"
    For k = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
        Cells(k, 1).Value = Sheets(k).Cells(i, j).Value
    Next k
End Sub
```